# if P = NP then N has an eigenspace that is at least rank(P)-dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra

So $N,P \in \mathbb{R}^{n x n}$ with $P \neq O$. I have to prove that if $$P = NP,$$ $N$ has an eigenspace that is at least rank($P$)-dimensional.

I haven't made a lot of progress because I don't know how to start proving this. If anyone has a hint to push me in the right direction, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I find $P=NP$ some false advertising for this question.

Comment: I'm not looking for attention or points, I just want this proof solved! It is what it is! From the rest of the title it's clear that it isn't THE P=NP problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P=NP\implies$ Each column of $P$ is an eigenvector of $N$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$.

Comment: What about the columns that are linearly dependant, do they also have eigenvalue 1 or do they just don't count?

Comment: Yep they also have eigenvalue $1$. Because if $p_k$ is $k$-th column of $P$, then $Np_k=p_k$. Now do you get it?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Partition the matrix $P$ into columns
$$
p=\begin{bmatrix}p_1 & p_2 & \ldots & p_n\end{bmatrix}
$$
and rewrite $P=NP$ in terms of the columns $p_k$. You will see the eigenvectors. Then use the definition of rank in terms of linear independent columns.

Comment: I see now that all columns of $P$ are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$. Let's say there are $k$ independant columns  $ k \leqslant n$ then the eigenspace has dimension $k$ and so is the $rank(A)$? Is that a good reasoning?

Comment: @WarreG If rank$(P)=k$ then there are $k$ linearly independent columns, hence, $k$ linearly independent eigenvectors with $\lambda=1$. However, it does not say that the eigenspace has the dimension $k$, because it may exist *more* linearly independent eigenvectors with $\lambda=1$ that **are not columns of $P$**. But we know that the dimension of the eigenspace is *at least* $k$.

Comment: Ah yes I see, thanks!